# Getting the difference between values in a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

Say I have two hashmaps modelone and modeltwo with values like this:

```
Hashmap<String, float> modelone, modeltwo, modelthree;
modelone.put("a", 1);
modelone.put("b", 3);
modelone.put("c", 2);

modeltwo.put("a", 3);
modeltwo.put("b", 1);
modeltwo.put("c", 7);
```

(String and float are used as there needs to be room for expansion in the data)

How would I be able to get the difference between the values in these hashmaps so that they result in new hashmap containg the differences between the values so that modelthree contains results like this:

```
("a", 2)
("b", 2)
("c", 5)
```

I will get the absolute difference between the numbers

Thanks.

Comment: How do you think you would do it?

Comment: HashMap can't contain `float`, and why `float` anyway?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - no, but it can contain `Float` just fine.  Though from the example, `Integer` would make more sense.  Though I assume that the snippet is just for illustration, since it doesn't instantiate `modelone` or `modeltwo` before using them.

Comment: @aroth That's why I asked for clarification. Also, String instead of Character.... what problem is actually being solved here... why not two List(s)?

Comment: So clearly you'll need to iterate through one of the maps, look up the keys you find in the other map, do some kind of subtraction, then store the result.  Which of these four things do you not know how to do?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate your map, computing the difference between the two values and storing it into your third map as you go.

For instance, something like:

```
for (String key : modelone.keySet()) {
    if (! modeltwo.containsKey(key)) {
        modelthree.put(key, modelone.get(key));
    }
    else {
        modelthree.put(key, (float)Math.abs(modelone.get(key) - modeltwo.get(key));
    }
}
```

Comment: And possibly adding the key/value pairs that are in `modeltwo` but not in `modelone` to `modelthree` as well (depends on the actual requirements).